# Highlight differences in multiple columns including False, 0 and blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

[Related to this question,](https://superuser.com/questions/1119505/and-function-gives-true-result-for-empty-blank-cell-why) I am trying to compare a table of settings to identify some configuration issues.  I am using the following formula to highlight differences between two known good configs (Columns B and C) and one that isn't working (Column D).

=OR($B2<>$D2,$C2<>$D2)

[image]

The problem I'm having is that values of `False`, `0` and `<blank>` all "match" according to Excel.

How can I adjust my formula to highlight these rows?

Comment: You could possibly just compare the length of the two strings. Otherwise you have to expand your formula to exclude those values using IsBlank etc

Comment: Provide some sample data, please. Or you may try to concat some constant char to the value - this will convert the value to text type, including empty cells values, something like `=OR($B2&"@"<>$D2&"@",$C2&"@"<>$D2&"@")`.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing them to evaluate as strings seems to result in the desired behavior.

```
=OR($B2&""<>$D2&"",$C2&""<>$D2&"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `COUNTIF`, it'll differentiate those values properly:

`=COUNTIF($B2:$C2,$D2)<2`

[image]